# Ubuntu 13.04 doesnt want to start upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Ubuntu 13.04 doesn’t want to start upgrade, It says that upgrade available (13.10), but when I hit Upgrade button Update window disappears and nothing happening... any Ideas?

Comment: update-manager -c worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start an upgrade using `update-manager -c` or `--check-dist-upgrades`:

> `-c, --check-dist-upgrades`                              Check if a new Ubuntu release is available